# Formatting mm:ss to string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting, ecmascript-6

I have a function that takes a time of minutes and seconds, and converts it to a string in the following way: '0:30' would become '30 Seconds', '1:30' would become '1 minute 30 seconds', '2:01' would become '2 minutes 1 second', etc.  My function works fine, but I'm wondering if there are areas for improvement.

```
function formatTime(formattedTime) {
  let minStr, secStr;
  let minNum = formattedTime.split(':')[0];
  let secNum = formattedTime.split(':')[1];
  if (minNum === '1') {
    minStr = 'minute';
  } else {
    minStr = 'minutes';
  }
  if (secNum === '01') {
    secStr = 'second';
    secNum = '1';
  } else {
    secStr = 'seconds';
  }
  if (minNum === '0') {
    return `${secNum} ${secStr}`;
  } else if (secNum === '00') {
    return `${minNum} ${minStr}`;
  } else {
    return `${minNum} ${minStr} ${secNum} ${secStr}`;
 }
}
```

Comment: `minNum` is easily confused with "minimum number", why not simply write `minutes` instead?

Comment: @le_m I felt it would be too repetitive to assign a variable to to it's own name as a string i.e. `minutes = 'minutes'`

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith "Too repetitive" is arguably a synonym of "easily understood", which is not a bad thing; code is not literary prose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a few changes to the function that I think improve readability.  By using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on the seconds, I eliminated the need to later set the `secNum` from `01` to `1`.  Since we no longer need to change that, the `minStr` and `secStr` can be set with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). I also used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to clean up the splitting of the time.

To make it less error prone, you'd also want to make sure to do some sanity checks on the input, as mentioned in the comments.

All told, it ended up looking like this:

```js
// Tests
console.log(formatTime('1:00'))
console.log(formatTime('1:01'))
console.log(formatTime('1:30'))
console.log(formatTime('0:30'))
console.log(formatTime('bad data'))

function formatTime(formattedTime) {
    // Set up minutes and seconds
    const [match, minNum, secNum] = formattedTime.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/) || [];
    
    // Make sure we're getting the data in correct
    if(!match) return false;

    // Get the correct minutes and seconds strings
    let minStr = (minNum === '1') ? 'minute' : 'minutes'
    let secStr = (parseInt(secNum) === 1) ? 'second' : 'seconds'

    // Return the formatted time
    if (parseInt(minNum) === 0) {
        return `${secNum} ${secStr}`;
    } else if (parseInt(secNum) === 0) {
        return `${minNum} ${minStr}`;
    } else {
        return `${minNum} ${minStr} ${parseInt(secNum)} ${secStr}`;
    }
}
```

This is making use of some ES6 additions, so if you want good browser support you'll need to make sure to run this through Babel.

Comment: damn, i was gonna write an answer but i got caught up in work stuff.. the only thing I was gonna say that you didn't mention is to sanitize the input.. `if(!formattedTime.match(/\d+:\d+/)) return false;`

Comment: also, your implementation will always show "seconds" because you're doing a strict comparison of a string to a number. better change the `1` to `'1'` or use `==` instead.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Oops...I originally had the `parseInt()` when splitting, but then I changed _that_ to destructuring and never updated elsewhere.

Comment: @le_m Good point on the extraneous declaration for `minStr` and `secStr`, updated!

Comment: @le_m Also included the combining of the variable assignment and sanity check.  Good call outs!

Comment: beware of using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) without passing the radix.... "_If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet._"

Comment: Looks good. Just a couple of questions: why use let instead of const? why parseInt the seconds but not the minutes?

Comment: @le_m I thought I removed that redundancy, but apparently not.  Stripped that out.

Comment: @tokland No reason on the `let` vs `const`.  Either should work.  I did the `parseInt` on the seconds to get rid of leading 0s.  Without it, you can end up with `03 seconds`.  I suppose you could do the same for minutes, it just didn't seem necessary at the time.

Comment: Am I the only person this doesn't work for, because the variables change from `minutes` & `seconds` to `minNum` & `secNum`? Also adding `0?` outside the brackets to both matches inside the pattern allows it to strip leading zeros on both at that point and avoid  the `parseInt`. (Alternatively you could just specifically call `parseInt` on both to avoid calling it multiple times for the same variable)

Comment: @USDMatt Fixed, snippet runs correctly.  My apologies, it has gone through a ton of revisions :)

Comment: @mathew-johnson Awesome, thanks.  It's just missing `if (parseInt(minNum, 10) === 0)`, otherwise it will return '0 minutes'